# How to trigger an electron app using a global keyboard + mouse keybinding?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'd like to take a screenshot from my Electron app whenever the user presses Command + Shift + Left Mouse Button Click on MacOS. I'll then use the mouse click location to highlight that area of the screenshot.

Electron has a [global shortcuts](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut) module that allows for listening to modifier keys combined with a [single key code](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/accelerator) which cannot be modifier key. How would I implement my desired behavior when I'm looking to trigger this logic based on a combined keyboard + mouse interaction?

If this is not possible, it'd also be acceptable to trigger the logic on command + shift without a non-modifier key, but this also does not seem to be possible from Electron's documentation.

If Electron cannot do this out of the box, is the only solution to create native C modules for each platform?